# Keyword not supported: 'metadata'. in Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

**I am working in asp.net mvc application, I want to set reminder of user request,
In startup.cs class i configure the hangfire.But it gives exception,Keyword not supported: 'metadata'. when read this line of code   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                   .UseSqlServerStorage("DbEntities");**

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using UKC.Data.Infrastructure;
using UKC.UI.Helper;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(UKC.UI.App_Start.Startup))]
namespace UKC.UI.App_Start
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
               .UseSqlServerStorage("DbEntities");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because of incorrect connection string in the configuration file.

```
        <add name="HangfireEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.DBModel.csdl|res://*/Model.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=HangfireTest;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=myStrongPassw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

should be

```
<add name="HangfireEntities" connectionString="Server=.\\localhost; Database=HangfireTest;user id=sa;password=myStrongPassw0rd" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```